# How to send one character at a time to a function in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have a function that takes one parameter of type `char`, of course that means only one character at a time.

I made a for-loop in order to send one character at a time to the function. But of course this wouldn't work, because `$mystring` is a string and can't be processed like a char. What would the solution be?

```
$mystring = "ABCDEFG";

function Characters {
    $lettertoascii = [int][char]$args[0];
}

for($i=1; $i -le 10; $i++){
    Characters $mystring
}
```

Comment: `$mystring.ToCharArray().ForEach({[int][char]$_[0]})`

Comment: If you make `Characters()` accept pipeline input, you could simply `[char[]]$myString | Characters`

Comment: Theoretically, `$mystring[$i]` in your loop would be possible, if it is what you initially searched for. The problem is, it would exceed the array bound.

Answer (score 1):

You could convert your string into a char array and process it with a foreach loop to call your function char by char:

```
$mystring = "ABCDEFG";

function characters{
     $lettertoascii = [int][char]$args[0];
}

$mystring.ToCharArray() | foreach {
    Characters $_
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest an advanced function:

```
function Get-Character
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [OutputType([System.Int32[]])]
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Position = 0, ValueFromPipeline)]
        [System.Char[]]
        $Letter
    )

    process
    {
        foreach ($item in $Letter)
        {
            [int]$item
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can pass a char array to it through pipeline:

```
'abcdefg' | Get-Character
```

or otherwise:

```
Get-Character 'abcdefg'
```

[Here's documentation on the `ToCharArray` method,](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.tochararray?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_ToCharArray) and [another link about advanced powershell functions.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced?view=powershell-5.1)

Edit:
Turns out powershell is smart and will automatically typecast a string to a char array so you can just pass a string.

Answer (score 1):

Or simply loop over the characters in the string like this:

```
$myString = 'ABCDEFG'
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $myString.Length; $i++) {
    # call your function one System.Char at a time
    Characters $myString[$i]
}
```

Comment: This gives me an idea.  Instead of strict typing the param of my function, we could just run a switch against the param `$Letter -is [string]` etc and take action from there. edit: nvm, powershell will typecast for you.